# afxambientactctx' undeclared identifier in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have a MFC project which is building fine in visual studio 2010 and when it got migrated to the visual studio2015 it is giving me the error:

> Error  C2065   'afxAmbientActCtx': undeclared identifier

Comment: Please show the corresonping source code line.

Comment: have you installed VC++ and MFC in 2015? by default VS2015 only installs C# and VB.net and no C++